# Querying nested/related entities in Entity Framework using Linq

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I have following Entities

```
public partial class Resource
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description{ get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ResourceCapability>  ResourceCapability { get; set; }
    }

 public partial class Capability
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description{ get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ResourceCapability> ResourceCapability   { get; set; }

    }

 public partial class ResourceCapability
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ResourceId { get; set; }
        public int CapabilityId { get; set; }

        public virtual Resource Resource { get; set; }
        public virtual Capability Capability { get; set; }
    }
```

Now a Resource can have multiple capabilities like C#, JAVA etc and a multiple resources can have same capabilities like more than one resources have C# capability and so on.

I am trying to get the list of all Resources having a particular (one or more) Capabilities. How do I do that using Linq?

Follwoing code returns me the list of the joining table and not the Resources

```
dbset.Select(x => x.ResourceCapability.Where(y => list.Contains(y.Capability.Description))).ToList();
```

where list is `List<string>` containing capability description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Follwoing code returns me the list of the joining table and not the
>   Resources

It's expected because linq `dbset.Select(x => x.ResourceCapability // ...` is a projection on `ResourceCapability` set.

Following query should work for you:

```
ctx.ResourceCapability.Where(x => list.Contains(x.Capability.Description)).Select(x => x.Resource).Distinct().ToList();
```

Here you select all `ResourceCapability` entities that contain capabilities from a list and then select distinct resources from those `ResourceCapability` items.

Comment: Thanks @codefuller. This works perfectly. I was looking more of a way to get capabilities directly from resources using the joining table somehow. But it seems that isnt possible and I have to query the joining table to get the list of either sides.